# Distancing `facet_grid` strips from the faceted canvas?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Consider the following example from the `?ggplot2::facet_grid`:

```
p <- ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, cty)) + geom_point()
p + facet_grid(vars(drv), vars(cyl))
```

Which results in the following image
[image]

What I would like to achieve is a minor offset/white space between the facet-labeling `strip`s and the actual plots. The result would look (sans the `gimp` involvement):
[image]

Is that possible using `ggplot2` or any of its derivative packages?

Thank you for any insight.

Comment: I can only think of this hack `theme(strip.background = element_rect(color = 'white', size = 3))`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Following up on @Tung's anser above (and some documentation-ignoring experimentation), I get it to work:

```
p <- ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, cty)) + geom_point() 
p +
  facet_grid(vars(drv), vars(cyl)) +
  theme(strip.switch.pad.grid = unit(0.2, "cm"), strip.placement = "outside")
```

And ... tada!:

[image]

Comment: What if you only want to change spacing between the top of chart and facet labels in columns? It seems there is no way to do this currently.

Answer (score 5):

There is an option `strip.switch.pad.grid` but it only works if you activate `switch` argument

```r
library(ggplot2)
theme_set(theme_bw(base_size = 14))

p <- ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, cty)) + geom_point()
p + facet_grid(vars(drv), vars(cyl), 
               switch = 'y') +
  theme(strip.placement = 'outside') +
  theme(strip.switch.pad.grid = unit('0.25', "cm"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-05-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>